# Set the separator(UIView)'s color based on the date and text in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set the separator(UIView)'s color based on the date and item text. The separator color will change to grey when the section date is before today string and the separator color will change to red when the jobDetail.text is "Cancel". Is it possible?

This is the code, I changed all the separator color but not specific. how to changed the separator based on section? or any other way to make the separator?

```
let section = ["Mon 18 May", "Tue 19 May", "Fri 22 May"]

let items = [["Work", "Work", "Cancel"], ["Off Day"], ["Work", "Work", "Work", "mushrooms"]]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.section[section]
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { 
    return self.section.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items [section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rosterId", for: indexPath) as! RosterCell

    cell.timeLabel.text = "10:00AM\n15:00PM"
    cell.jobDetail?.text = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    let today = "19 May 2017"
    let headerDate = "18 May 2017"

    if headerDate < today{
        cell.separator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8314, blue: 0.1569, alpha: 1)
    }else if cell.jobDetail.text == "Cancel"{
        cell.separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }   
    return cell
}
```

App Layout
[image]

My Code Result
[image]

Comment: What is your date format you need to compare with today date ?

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are comparing string objects that's why this is not working try this :

```
let today = Date()
let headerDate = "18 May 2017"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy" //Your date format
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
//Current time zone
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: headerDate) //according to date format your date string
print(date ?? "")

if today < date{
    cell.separator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8314, blue: 0.1569, alpha: 1)
} else if cell.jobDetail.text == "Cancel" {
    cell.separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: But it will still change all the separator's color right? How to change the separator based on the index path or section..?

Comment: set color as you needed like if date > headerDate // set color , else if date < headerDate//  else if cell.jobDetail.text == "Cancel" //set color else // color then this will always work as you expected.

Comment: I fixed it by other way but inspired by your code, can I update my code to yr answer?

Comment: You are comparing the date incorrectly because you are not disregarding the time correctly. Use `Calendar.current.compare(today, to: date, toGranularity: .day) == .ascending` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Alway Convert your string to date then compare it

```
    let today = "19 May 2017" // Date() for today
    let headerDate = "18 May 2017"

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    let todayDate = dateFormatter.date(from: today)!

    let headerDateDate = dateFormatter.date(from: headerDate)!
    if headerDateDate < todayDate{
        cell.separator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8314, blue: 0.1569, alpha: 1)
    }else if cell.jobDetail.text == "Cancel"{
       cell.separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
   }   
   return cell
```